# Delphi 10 TRestClient MIME boundary issue

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to consume a REST service using `TRestClient` but I believe there is an issue with the `boundary` string for multipart content.

I am capturing the body of the request I am sending, and this is the content type header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------Embt-Boundary--07CC944C29DA577E
```

Then, this is the first section of the multipart form:

```
-----------Embt-Boundary--07CC944C29DA577E
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ce.csv"
Content-Type: text/csv
```

And this is how it ends:

```
---------Embt-Boundary--07CC944C29DA577E--
```

I don't think this is an issue on the server, as even my proxy is not able to parse the body:

[image]

When I compare this same request vs postman, I notice that the starting and ending boundaries do not match!

```
Starting: -----------Embt-Boundary--07CC944C29DA577E
Ending:   ---------Embt-Boundary--07CC944C29DA577E--
```

I found that the `boundary` generation is done in `TMultipartFormData.GenerateBoundary()` from `System.Net.Mime`:

[image]

When checking the starting and ending boundaries from postman, they match, so I am almost sure this is the issue. I don't think it is related to my code, but let me know if you need it.

Comment: The starting boundary on the MIME body you are capturing is wrong. Whatever value is specified in the `boundary` attribute of the `Content-Type` header, each boundary in the body must be prefixed with `--`, and the last boundary must be suffixed with `--`. IOW, given `boundary=<value>`, each starting boundary is `--<value>` and the ending boundary is `--<value>--`. But in your case, the starting boundary is `----<value>` instead, which is wrong (the ending boundary is fine). So this is clearly a bug in `TRestClient` and should be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed, seems to be a bug in System.Net.Mime TMultipartFormData.AdjustLastBoundary. By changing FStream.Position := FStream.Size - (Length(FBoundary) + 4) to FStream.Position := FStream.Size - (Length(FBoundary) + 6) to include that 2 additional dashes issue is fixed. Link to the report: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27968